# Publishing asp.net core

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a problem when publishing my web application to IIS. 
The application works fine when running it locally, after the publishing I get the following error when accessing view which requires connection to the database (MYSQL):
[image: Error message]

In the publishing profile the following string is added:

```
server=localhost;userid=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;database=mydb;SslMode=none.
```

The IIS server is running locally, on the same machine as the database.

The issue seems to be happening everytime I use the database context.

Should the "Entity Framework Migrations" (the database used is the same) be enabled in the publishing profile, and if so how do I define the Connection string (as the one from the "Databases" option doesn't work)?

When developer mode is activated (through VS), the error isn't there anymore..

Comment: You need to enable Development Mode as currently the error message gives absolutely no clues as to the cause of the problem. Please search on Google for more information. Also, this question is off topic here - StackOverflow would be more suitable but only once you have found the actual error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is when I enable the Development Mode, and run it through Visual Studio, there are no errors.. Should I move it, even though, I don't know the code error yet?